# Warning: sqlite_query() [function.sqlite-query]: attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: php, sqlite

The error-Warning: sqlite_query() [function.sqlite-query]: attempt to write a readonly database is coming whenever i try to insert values into a sqllite 1.1 database thru php program.
php version is 5.2.

Comment: Just an hint: Do you have write access on it at least ?

Comment: SQLite 1.1? PHP only has support SQLite 2 and 3 (IIRC SQLite 2 support was also dismissed a while ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> attempt to write a readonly database

Beyond the version issues that have already been pointed out, this error happens under two circumstances:

1. The file *is* owned by the same user running PHP, and permissions on the file *or* directory are not wide enough to allow PHP to modify the file
2. The file *is not* owned by the same user running PHP, and permissions on the file *or* directory are not wide enough to allow PHP to modify the file

Correct either ownership or permissions, and the problem will be resolved.